# Netbeans 8.0 IDE is stuck on Refreshing indices (1% complete)

Tags: java, netbeans

Netbeans 8.0 for Java project is stuck on Refreshing indices (1% complete) for hours.

Restart IDE make no difference. Environment is ...

```
 Netbeans 8.0  
 OSX 10.9.2 
 JDK 1.8.0_05
```

All was working good up to now.

How to get the IDE back to a good state ?

I did read http://forums.netbeans.org/topic60391.html but I think it is discussing a different project type that I use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe clearing the cache directory of Netbeans could boost the IDE. The path can be found under "About".

Comment: Thanks. All back to normal now. In my setup this did the trick...     rm -rf /Users/<user>/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.0/*

Answer (score 0):

Well, this thread may be a bit too old to get back to but in my case, the problem was a project data folder with a lot of json files; +100k files. It was a data folder with files generated by the program.

Rule of thumb: if you can, keep your data folders outside your project.

Comment: I think for what you describe telling NB to ignore that folder would be enough? See https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/ignored-files-in-netbeans-ide